# Cookies with non-ASCII causing all endpoints to give status code 400

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a website using aspnetcore 2.1 and Kestrel (IIS as proxy) and *someone else* on our domain sets a cookie that contains non-ASCII characters. [I know this is wrong](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1076), but I can't make sure they don't and *I still want the cookie* (otherwise it is easy just to remove it in my web.config).

The result being: Cookie is set incorrectly on one site and when the user "unknowingly" goes to our website, our website gives an error 400 on **all requests**.

Is there a way of removing the bad characters in the cookie header before it hits Kestrel? I thought I could use a HttpModule/Middleware/etc to remove it, but it looks like Kestrel is the first one to get a `HttpContext`.

Comment: Have you tried removing it in IIS?

Comment: @Brad of course. The "problem" is that I can't get to the HttpContext before Kestrel. So I assume the IIS would probably be the solution to the problem..

Comment: Imho the correct approach would be to contact the other team who created your other application and fix it there, since by HTTP specification its invalid to have this characters in the cookie. Also your teams should learn how to configure cookies so that they are only available on  a specific domain or path (i.e. only set cookie for /App1 path but your new app will set it to /App2, this way /App1 cookies won't be sent to /App2

Comment: @Tseng: Oh I agree! I have reported a bug, so it is going to be evaluated, estimated, prioritized, broken down into smaller tasks, escalated to dependent teams that the cookie will be encoded and how etc. 
How about the user experience? What's your take on that? Shall we make users of x.microsoft.com receive error 400 because of the cookies from y.microsoft.com for a couple of months (or until utopia comes)? Or shall we make a temporary fix until then?

Comment: It's the same as complaining that a mail server sends invalid mime mails and expecting all mail clients to fix that on their side. It just encourages people to keep the broken stuff in place, cause "others will fix it" :)

Comment: Maybe, or if the settings you made in Excel would cause Outlook to send invalid mime mails and you couldn't tell why or make it stop.

Answer (score 0):

No workaround at the side of dotnetcore. If you are using nginx behind of your dotnetcore application, you can delete all of the non-ascii character like that:

```
    set_by_lua_block $cookie_ascii {
        local cookie = ngx.var.http_cookie
        if cookie == nil or cookie == '' then return cookie end
        local cookie_ascii, n, err = ngx.re.gsub(cookie, "[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")
        return cookie_ascii
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:5000;
        ...
        proxy_set_header    Cookie $cookie_ascii;
        ...
    }    
}
```